# 3 pin ethernet module?

Tags: pins, spi, ethernet

So basically I'm working on a project that uses an Atmega328 like on the Arduino Uno. I need to receive both DMX (with max485) and E131 (Not both at the same time, I'll decide which with a boolean in the sketch) and then use that to control 16 channels. I need the TX and RX pins (UART) for the max485 (DMX), 16 outputs for the triacs, and 1 pin for zero-cross detection. If I use the Analog pins as digital outputs, that lets 3 pins to connect the ethernet module. Most of them use 4 pins, I believe it's SPI. I only have 3 available. Is this possible? Also, I may need a second zero-cross detector, so is it possible with 2 pins then?
Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like you need either an MCU with more pins or a second MCU for the ethernet.

Comment: Are there ethernet modules that use, say, i2c?

Comment: did you try to add Ethernet library to your sketch? don't you run out of flash?

Comment: you could use some UART module. esp8266 WiFi module uses Serial.

Comment: No, I havent actually made a sketch yet. Just trying to figure out the hardware side first.

Comment: And what do you mean by uart module and esp8266? I specifically need it to be ethernet, not wifi.

Comment: https://www.waveshare.com/uart-to-eth.htm it uses an MCU

Comment: I haven't heard of any I2C Ethernet modules, no, but that doesn't mean there aren't any. But then it wouldn't be too hard to write a sketch for an Arduino that has an Ethernet card on it and communicates over I2C with your existing setup.

Comment: Yes, your right I could use a uart ethernet module and then put a physical switch or jumper to connect one or the other. Those are kinda expensive tho, not sure why.

Comment: Also I don't need cs because I only have 1 chip connected to SPI bus right? That would get me down to 3 pins. And then do I need a tx for E131? Does the arduino need to send something to say that the packet was received, or to help connect it to a pc? Or can I just use RX only? If so, that would get me down to the 2 pins I need.

Comment: the W5x00 don't work without switching CS input

Comment: Could it just be constantly pulled high or low?

Comment: no. the logic in chip reads the CS signal edges